# UDP forwarding not always working

Tags: openvpn, port-forwarding, udp

I have a udp forwarding to a VM with the rule

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 42000:42020 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.2/32 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.2 -p udp --dport 42000:42020 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.2 -j ACCEPT
```

In the VM is are openvpn servers listening on these ports.

Now I have a strange problem with the forwarding on the host: Some packets are routed between the interfaces and some are not, without a clear pattern why.

- One VPN connection is working just fine. tcpdump shows packets on `eth0` and `vmnet` on the host and inside the VM.
- Three VPN connections are getting peer packets on `eth0` which are not routed to `vmnet` and vm packets on `vmnet` which are not routed to `eth0`.
- UDP packets with the same sourceport and packet length as one of the failing connections sent via netcat are logged on `eth0`, `vmnet` and inside the VM just fine.

What can I try to find why the packets are not routed to the other interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has two parts:

First libvirt inserted a firewall rule with

```
- j MASQUERADE --to-port 1024-65535
```

which changed source ports, which do not match other rules and cause errors in openvpn.

The complicated part is, why disabling this did not work. And there the conntrack table kept the information about the source port alive. I guess the packets from the peer, which were still coming in trying to reconnect, updated the entry in the table.

When I ran `conntrack -D` (be careful, this will drop all tracked connections), the packets started to have the correct source port.
Note that conntrack cannot ensure the source port, but if available tries to use the original one, if no `--to-ports` parameter is used.